# Retrieve value of links from Google Sheet?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I have some values in a Google Sheet, some of which are hyperlinked, like the third one here:

[image]

I want to retrieve the text value of each cell, and the hyperlink if present.

I am able to access the sheet easily enough with [gspread](http://gspread.readthedocs.io):

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    './credentials.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
key = 'xxxxx'
wks = gc.open_by_key(key).worksheets()
for wk in wks:
    links = wk.col_values(3)
    for l in links:
       print l.value
```

However, this only prints the string value of the links, not the actual href that the link is pointing to.

Does anyone know if it's possible to retrieve this programmatically, using gspread or another library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `gspread`, a `Cell` instance has an undocumented attribute `input_value` that gives you access to the formula.

```
>>> formula = mycell.input_value
>>> formula
'=HYPERLINK("https://url.com","Link Text")'
>>> lst = formula.split('"')
>>> lst[1], lst[3]
('https://url.com', 'Link Text')
```

From there you just need to split the string to remove the undesired parts.

In your case, you may want to subclass `gspread.Worksheet` like so:

```
class CustomWorksheet(gspread.Worksheet):
    def get_links(self, col):
        """Returns a list of all links urls in column `col`.
           Empty cells in this list will be rendered as :const:`None`.
        """
        start_cell = self.get_addr_int(1, col)
        end_cell = self.get_addr_int(self.row_count, col)

        row_cells = self.range('%s:%s' % (start_cell, end_cell))
        return [cell.input_value.split('"')[1] for cell in row_cells if cell.input_value.startswith('=HYPERLINK')]
```

Comment: I have used input_value but I am getting None not even the text. I think input_value is deprecated now.

Comment: @ChaithanyaKrishna You are absolutely correct, this is deprecated. The correct way to do this now is using the `value_render_option` keyword argument, e.g. `worksheet.cell(1, 1, value_render_option='FORMULA')`

Comment: The docs for `value_render_option` are here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption

Comment: Thanks for the response Jacques. I have tried value_render_option as well with all the three possible but it didn't worked

Comment: @ChaithanyaKrishna I haven't tried it but it's the replacement stated in the source code. You should probably ask a new question showing what you have tried and didn't work.